Is there a way to truncate data in an intermediary table after a period of time in snowflake
I am building DBT models integrating with snowflake, where I have landing model(table), staging model(incremental) and presentation model(incremental) and a view ontop of the presentation model for access. the staging model contains the transformation process and the data is not useful to downstream, while the presentation has the transformed data to be consumed by downstream. To conserve storage cost, I was hoping to truncate the data in the staging after a period of time. Is there a way to do this? or is there an better approach to conserving storage cost. Or do I have to leave the data in the staging for data linage purposes?

Whether you need to keep the data for data lineage purposes is something only you can know.
The storage costs, unless you have massive data volumes, are unlikely to be enough to warrant deleting data - but, again, a decision only you can take.
To delete data just schedule a task that deletes data older than x days
